# Displaying Current date instead of yesterday's date in DB2

Tags: sql, database, db2

I created a variable using the following definition.

```
create variable ABCDATE varchar(26) default((select (current_date - 1 day) from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1))
```

When i displayed the variable ABCDATE using the schema name(SchemaName.ABCDATE), it displayed current date. ideally it should return yesterday's date. In what all situatons, it happens like this?

Comment: ... you may be falling victim to differences in timezones.  What's _your_ (session) timezone, versus that of the db (which is often UTC)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you create a variable containing a date as a VARCHAR?

This works for me

```
create variable wiltc.abcdate date default(current_date - 1 day)
```

Displaying

```
select wiltc.abcdate from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Note that if you expect the value to change automatically, it won't.  The value is set when the varibale is created and wouldn't be updated again.

You'd be better served by having a view

```
create view yesterday 
  as (select current_date - 1 day as thedate
      from sysibm.sysdummy1
     )
```

Comment: +1 just for pointing out issues with expecting the value to update, although I'm suspicious of the need to have a variable for _yesterday_ (which is easy to derive)...